# Gatsby blog path broken after append Facebook fbclid?

Tags: html, facebook, url, gatsby, query-string

I have blog with Gatsby. Everything work when access blog post direct. For example when call this page load no problem: [www.website.com/blog/blog-post-1](http://www.website.com/blog/blog-post-1)

But when post to Facebook Facebook append fbclid: [www.website.com/blog/blog-post-1?fbclid=XXXXX](http://www.website.com/blog/blog-post-1?fbclid=XXXXX)
Then when click this url this then make Gatsby blog post not load.

How to fix??

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue ??